# Performance and usage of multiple keys index

Tags: sql, sql-server

Working with SQL Server, I was given a project where a table has an non-clustered index with two keys, `CompanyID` and `EmployeeID`. I was always under the impression that I had to do a query that had both keys involved to make the lookup fast.

For example:

```
select * from tblTable where CompanyID = 100 and EmployeeID = 1234
```

but if I just search for one column, then it does not use this index right?

```
select * from tblTable where CompanyID = 100
```

Is that correct? I was always under the impression I had to make a separate index for each column I wanted to search on fast and that the multi-key indexes were if I needed to do unique combinations of the two keys.

Comment: What index SQL uses depends on the statistics. It is not depended on how many keys are in the index and what order they are. It might not even use the index if for example the table is small enough to read with a table scan. It has to do with O-notation or operational efficiency

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily - it depends on the order of the keys inside the index.

In your case, if the index is on `(CompanyID, EmployeeID)`, then that index might be used for queries that include both columns, but it will **also** be potentially useful on queries that include only `CompanyID` in their `WHERE` clause.

However, it will **NEVER** be able to be used for queries that use only the `EmployeeID` column in their `WHERE` clause. If you had a lot of queries on just the `EmployeeID`, you might investigate the possibility of having a separate, additional index on just `EmployeeID` for those queries.

In general, a multi-column index might be useful of the n left-most columns are used, e.g. just `CompanyID` (1 left-most column) or `CompanyID` and `EmployeeID` (2 left-most columns).

Comment: So someone making a single index with columns they think they are indexing individually is just not doing it correctly. From your explanation, in a single column look-up operation, on the first column in the list will use a index search, while a lookup using of other other columns in the table will do a table search, is that correct?  I need to explain this to the management and need to be sure.  Thanks!

Comment: @CHris: well, almost - if you do search for just one row out of millions, then the first step is the index search in the non-clustered index - which is fast. Then, if additional pieces of data are needed, a second search is made, using the **clustering key** (which is present in each and every non-clustered index automatically), which probably will be a clustered index seek. This works fine and performs well as long as you have just a few rows to be found. This gets really bad for performance if you select hundreds or thousands of rows

Comment: @marc_s Does the sorting of the columns in the index matters? If i Have a index on ComapnyID and EmployeeID but do a `WHERE EmployeeID = X AND CompanyId = Y`, the index is used? If not, I setup two indexes then for cover both cases?

Answer (score 0):

SQL server will evaluate if the index can be used based on the cost and the cost is estimated based on how selective your value is. If the column you filter is not the first column of and index, you can get an index scan, but not an index seek. BUT as you are using SELECT * you'll probably end up with a clustered index scan.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.x
(
a int,
b int,
c int,
d int
)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix1 ON dbo.X (a);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix2 ON dbo.X (b,c);
INSERT INTO dbo.X (a,b,c) VALUES(1,1,1);
SELECT * FROM dbo.X WHERE b=1 --will probably use a clustered index scan
SELECT a FROM dbo.X WHERE b=1 --can use a non-clustered index seek (a is in the index as it's part of the clustered index key
SELECT a FROM dbo.X WHERE c=1 --will probably use a nonclustered index scan as c is not the first column
SELECT a,d FROM dbo.X WHERE b=1 --will probably use a clustered index scan as d is not part of the index
```